# How to create Hex File Compiler in C#

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, microcontroller, microchip

Please is there anyway I can plugin or Integrate a PIC MCU into my C# Code so that I can create a text editor and also compile code with my Software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Pigmeo](http://urriellu.net/en/projects-software/pigmeo-compiler-framework-c-sharp-microcontrollers.html) framework & compiler.

Comment: Pigmeo doesn't support many PIC devices and not functional since 2012, I guess the developers has stop working on the project.

Comment: @Bytehub Though thats the only one i know for C#.